# Disable long indentation of new anonymous classes in Android Studio / IntelliJ

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

[image]

I want normal indentation in there, maybe 1.5 of the value set to tab size, anyone knows how to fix this?

I've spent the last 15 minutes looking at the configuration in Settings -> Editor -> Java -> Tabs and Indent / Wrapping and Bracers and can't find it.

Comment: Not having worked with this IDE before, it looks to me like it's somehow linked to the column position of `new Callback<...`, as opposed to `call.enqueue...`.

Comment: yea well, i kind of found a "way" to make this look better, moving the new statement to a new line, now all i have is a line that reads call.enqueue(.. i'm going to keep it like that for now, much better than having a huge white rectangle in there